# GRASS GIS producing different slope than GDAL?

Tags: gdal, grass-gis, slope

When producing a slope in GRASS GIS 7.4 the results are different than with QGIS (GDAL) and ArcMap for the same input data and same parameter (Z ratio is 1.0 and degrees). QGIS and ArcMap generate almost the same output. In GRASS, I tried both for DCELL and FCELL and the results are same. The original layer has a resolution on 1 m and the GRASS region resolution is set to 0.5 m.

Code GRASS: `r.slope.aspect elevation=DMR@PERMANENT slope=slope`

Code GDAL: `gdaldem slope .../DMR.tif .../slope.tif -of GTiff -b 1 -s 1.0`

Do I do something wrong?
I am attaching the screenshots of the situation.

[image: Left - GRASS calculated slope and right - GDAL calculated one]
Left - GRASS calculated slope and right - GDAL calculated one

Comment: What is the difference if you set the grass region to the raster resolution? `g.region raster=DMR@PERMANENT`? (with and without the `-a` option)

Comment: No difference. I i tried both and in both situations the same slope results.

Comment: Right - nor should it. I read the `r.slope.aspect` docs and it says it adjusts the region to the raster. Can you share the file?

Comment: Hi @mankoff I uploaded you a TIF [LZW] on wetrasnfer. Thank you very much. https://we.tl/t-YO1VNmDgAW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the replies by  **mankoff** and **mmetz** from trac.osgeo:

**I think the issue is related to the region.**

**There is a work-around for the bug: `g.region raster=<raster> -a`**

The r.slope.aspect documentation in the NOTES section implies that the region is adjusted to the raster. I do not find that to be the case. Specifically in the NC test data, I've created the following slope rasters, and then looked at their univariate statistics:

`g.region raster=elevation
r.slope.aspect elevation=elevation slope=slope_0
r.slope.aspect -a elevation=elevation slope=slope_1
g.region res=30 -pa
r.slope.aspect elevation=elevation slope=slope_2
r.slope.aspect -a elevation=elevation slope=slope_3`

`for i in $(seq 0 3); do
  (echo -n "slope_${i} "; r.univar slope_${i} | grep range) | tr '\n' ' '
done`

Results are:

`slope_0 range: 36.3347 
slope_1 range: 36.3347 
slope_2 range: 13.7754 
slope_3 range: 25.3968`

[ticket](https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/3860)

Comment (by **mmetz**):

Replying to [comment:15 mankoff]:

> Running `r.univar` at the region resolution (as above) or at the raster
>    resolution:
>
> {{{
>   for r in $(g.list mapset=. type=raster); do
>     g.region raster=${r} -a
>     (echo -n "${r} "; r.univar ${r} | grep range)
>   done | sort | tac
>   }}}
>
> Does not change anything.

Right, **this was a bug in r.slope.aspect, alignment to the input raster did
 not work** (difference between `G_get_window()` and `Rast_get_window()`).
 **Fixed in master, relbr76, and relbr74**

Comment: Glad you spotted this!

Comment: The bug has been fixed as of today and will be published in GRASS GIS 7.4.5, 7.6.2 and 7.8.0 (find here their respective release dates: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/roadmap)

Comment: Suggested edit, to be placed at top and/or highlighted: There is a work-around for the bug: `g.region raster=<raster> -a`.

Comment: @mankoff done! and thanks again